# which aws instance types need subnet id specified?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Cloud formation says:

> The specified instance type can only be used in a VPC. A subnet ID or
>   network interface ID is required to carry out the request. Launching
>   EC2 instance failed.

Which instance types do not need a subnet ID or network interface ID?

Comment: You should *always* use a VPC.

Answer (score 0):

> Which instance types do not need a subnet ID or network interface ID?

There is no instance type that does not require those things. EC2 Instance is a Virtual Cloud Compute so you need them to define where the instance will be deployed on and how network can connect to that instance. 
If you use AWS console wizard, it sopports you to run quickly so you don't need to specify those information, wizard will create them for you. 
But if you use CloudFormation, you must define manually.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have an older AWS account, you may still have access to EC2 "Classic", which means it is possible to launch an instance without needing a VPC.  Only accounts created before Dec. 2013 support EC2 Classic.

However, not every instance type supports being launched into EC2 Classic - in fact, most of the newer instance types can only be launched into a VPC.

The full list is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html#vpc-only-instance-types), but the M/C/R4 families plus T2s, are VPC only.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is "Which instance types can be launched without a VPC"?

Very old AWS accounts were NOT automatically creating a default VPC and there might be some instance types (I don't know which instance types) could be launched without a VPC.

Currently all AWS account will create a default VPC and you can create all instances ONLY inside a VPC.